# How to embed a view into the teaser of a node?

Tags: views, nodes

On the main page, I have a view that lists 3 items (3 boxes). One of them is linking to the news section. Right now, it's only a plain node and only the teaser is displayed on the front page.

If it's possible, I want to include the top 3 news headlines within the teaser of this node. Basically this will be a view inside of a teaser that is also listed to the front page by a view.

I might succeed with [this method](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14103/how-do-i-embed-a-view-inside-a-node) but I want to avoid using PHP as a text format. Should I just create a module and insert the view into the teaser by code? Is there a more convenient way?

Answer (score 2):

You can install and activate the [Field views](http://drupal.org/project/field_views) module, and add the field type to your content type. Configure it for your view.

Then edit your content type, and under 'Manage Display' configure the field to be visible in your teaser.

Comment: Entity Views Attach works, too.