# Button in block

Tags: 7, blocks

I want to add a *"View File"* button in Drupal 7 website. A PDF file associated with it, should open in new tab. The problem is that this button should be added inside a block.

I want to ask that how to add a button in a block?

Comment: Is this a node's file field?

Answer (score 1):

For multiple files:

1. Create a View
2. Add your file field and set "Formatter" as "URL to file".
3. Try rewriting the field as `<a href="[YOUR_FIELD]" target="_blank">Go to file</a>`
4. You could embed this [view in a block as php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14103/how-do-i-embed-a-view-inside-a-node#answer-38735). The simplest way would be to use the PHP Filter located in D7 core, but there are some reasons not to use it.

For just one file, use:

```
<a href="/sites/default/files/your-file.pdf" target="_blank">Go to file</a>
```